# Как в angularjs отфильтровать объект?

Tags: angularjs, filter

Как в angularjs отфильтровать объект?

Например есть объект со свойствами Name,Age... мне нужно вывести все,например, где Name='Roman' и Age= 26

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Описания и примеры как работать с фильтрами https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter